# 2016 answer to sync SQL Azure with local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014, data-synchronization

SQL Data Sync Tool is old and unsupported for PROD. It is also for SQL Server 2012, Azure has SQL Server 2014 now..

I simply need a way to sync my local full version of SQL Server 2014 with Azure SQL database.. both ways... meaning I want to pull down the azure version locally.. AND push my local version up.. at will.

The permissions are totally different and break when you use sync tools..

Has ANYONE solved this for 2016?  All the answers I see say to use manually options or SQL Data Sync Tool..either of which work for us.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be SQL data sync as you mention.  We hope to be able to share more plans in this space soon.

Guy